# Databind in knockoutjs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze, hottowel

Working with knockout js and breezejs i have a select control what is working in a strange way, this because sometimes the dropdown is populated fine and sometimes not( so my issue is with the property options: sites)

**Layout:**

```
 <select data-bind="options: sites, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedSite, optionsCaption:  'All Sites'" class="input-medium"></select>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
export var sites = ko.observableArray();


function loadSites() {
   return datacontext.getSites(sites, globalSettings.TreeViewObject,   globalSettings.UserId, globalSettings.DeviceType);
}
```

where datacontext is:

```
export var getSites = function (sitesObservable, treeViewObject,userId,deviceType) {       
  var query = EntityQuery.from("GetSites")
      .withParameters({ userId: userId, businessObject: treeViewObject, deviceType: deviceType});


return manager.executeQuery(query)
    .then(querySucceeded)
    .fail(queryFailed);

function querySucceeded(data) {
    if (sitesObservable) {
        sitesObservable(data.results);
    }
    log('Retrieved [Sites] from remote data source',
        data, true);
}
```

}

The execution of loadSites method come from the next method:

```
function loadLookupsAtRootLevel() {
   return Q.all([<any>loadLookup3(), <any>loadSites(), <any>loadLookup2(), <any>loadLookup3(), <any> loadLookup4()]);
}
```

so i can all my lookups from

```
export function activate() {
    return loadLookupsAtRootLevel().then(loadRegistrations);
```

}

from logging i can see that the collection is retrieved in a correct way but for some strange reason the control is not updated. Console in google chrome don't show any error. I don't how to debug the issue. any ideas?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? "in a strange way, this because sometimes the binding is correct and sometimes not." What is not working the population of the drop-down so the items are not there or the preselection of the drop-down so not the correct item is selected?

Comment: question update. my issue is with property options: sites since that my dropdown is not getting the items all the time.

Comment: @Rolando in the statement `sitesObservable(data.results);`, the `data.results` variable returns a javascript array where **each** element of this array has a property called `name`?

Comment: yes you right @BernardoPacheco, every row in the data return a collection of object where each object has the property name.

Comment: Have you tried reducing `loadLookupsAtRootLevel()` to just calling `loadSites()`?  That might make it easier to figure out what is happening.  Maybe KO is getting confused when so many async things are Q'd up together.